# Clean way to search through associations

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-4

I have the following schema:

```
class Service < ActiveRecord::Base
  has_many :orders

class Table < ActiveRecord::Base
  has_many :orders

class Order < ActiveRecord::Base
  belongs_to :table
  belongs_to :service
```

[image]

For one `service` and one `table` I have an `order`.
I want to have a `concern` to set the order.

```
module CurrentOrder
  extend ActiveSupport::Concern
  private
    def set_order
      @order = .......
    end
end
```

What is the clean "railistic" way to find this order?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It ideally depend on your results. 
Assume you have table_id and service_id, so you does not have to load table & service

```
order = Order.where(table_id: table_id, service_id: service_id).first
```

Comment: Consider the scenario in which i have both service_id & table_id, so i does not have to load both. I directly going to query order. I have written above that it usually depend on results & info we have at hand.

Answer (score 2):

Assuming you have `service` and `table` variables holding `Service` and `Table` instances respectively:

```
order = service.orders.find_by(table_id: table.id)
```

Answer (score 1):

You can simply do it

```
service = Service.first #lets you take first service orders
table = Table.last #lets you take orders of last table
orders  = service.orders.where(table_id: table.id)
```